Adding login hint for split email verification password custom policy
I have a custom policy that is based on the sample provided here https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup to have the email verification and password split between two separate screens.
I've been trying to add the the login_hint to have the email field pre-filled but there is some strange behavior. I tried to add the following
<Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>

  
     
   
In the email verification below
<ClaimsProvider>
     <DisplayName>Email Verification</DisplayName>
     <TechnicalProfiles>
        <!--Email verification only-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="EmailVerification">
           <DisplayName>Initiate Email Address Verification For Local Account</DisplayName>
           <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
           <Metadata>
              <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccount.emailVerification</Item>
              <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
              <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">True</Item>
              <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
           </Metadata>
           <InputClaims>
              <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
           </InputClaims>
           <OutputClaims>
              <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
           </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
     </TechnicalProfiles>
  </ClaimsProvider>

It seems to work, however when it reads the email from the login hint, the verification button somehow disappears, and the user can proceed without verifying his email. If it does not detect a login hint and the user actually has to enter his email, then the verification button is there.
Below is the complete policy ( without the changes above ). If anyone has any idea what the issue is, I would be happy to hear about it. Thanks
<TrustFrameworkPolicy
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="contactifybiztest.onmicrosoft.com" PolicyId="B2C_1A_signup_only" PublicPolicyUri="http://contactifybiztest.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_only" TenantObjectId="76293fdb-8269-4ba9-a113-d99adce461c3">
   <BasePolicy>
      <TenantId>contactifybiztest.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
      <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
   </BasePolicy>
   <BuildingBlocks>
      <ClaimsSchema>
         <!-- Read only email address to present to the user-->
         <ClaimType Id="readonlyEmail">
            <DisplayName>E-mail Address</DisplayName>
            <DataType>string</DataType>
            <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
         </ClaimType>
      </ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimsTransformations>
         <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
            <InputClaims>
               <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
            </InputClaims>
            <InputParameters>
               <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
            </InputParameters>
            <OutputClaims>
               <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readonlyEmail" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
            </OutputClaims>
         </ClaimsTransformation>
      </ClaimsTransformations>
      <ContentDefinitions>
         <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccount.emailVerification">
            <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
            <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
            <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.8</DataUri>
            <Metadata>
               <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
            </Metadata>
            <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
               <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.localaccount.emailVerification.en" />
            </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
         </ContentDefinition>
      </ContentDefinitions>
      <Localization Enabled="true">
         <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
            <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
         </SupportedLanguages>
         <LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccount.emailVerification.en">
            <LocalizedStrings>
               <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="button_continue">Continue</LocalizedString>
            </LocalizedStrings>
         </LocalizedResources>
      </Localization>
   </BuildingBlocks>
   <ClaimsProviders>
      <ClaimsProvider>
         <DisplayName>Email Verification</DisplayName>
         <TechnicalProfiles>
            <!--Email verification only-->
            <TechnicalProfile Id="EmailVerification">
               <DisplayName>Initiate Email Address Verification For Local Account</DisplayName>
               <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
               <Metadata>
                  <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccount.emailVerification</Item>
                  <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
               </Metadata>
               <OutputClaims>
                  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
               </OutputClaims>
            </TechnicalProfile>
         </TechnicalProfiles>
      </ClaimsProvider>
      <ClaimsProvider>
         <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
         <TechnicalProfiles>
            <!--Sign-up self-asserted technical profile without Email verification-->
            <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail">
               <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
               <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
               <Metadata>
                  <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
                  <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
                  <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
                  <!-- Remove sign-up email verification -->
                  <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">False</Item>
               </Metadata>
               <InputClaimsTransformations>
                  <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" />
               </InputClaimsTransformations>
               <InputClaims>
                  <!--Sample: Set input the ReadOnlyEmail claim type to prefilled the email address-->
                  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" />
               </InputClaims>
               <OutputClaims>
                  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                  <!-- Sample: Display the ReadOnlyEmail claim type (instead of email claim type)-->
                  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" Required="true" />
                  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
                  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
                  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
                  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
                  <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
               </OutputClaims>
               <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                  <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
               </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
               <!-- Sample: Disable session management for sign-up page -->
               <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
            </TechnicalProfile>
         </TechnicalProfiles>
      </ClaimsProvider>
   </ClaimsProviders>
   <UserJourneys>
      <UserJourney Id="SignUp">
         <OrchestrationSteps>
            <!-- Start with email verification -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
               <ClaimsExchanges>
                  <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange_EmailVerification" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerification" />
               </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <!-- Proceed to the sign-up page -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
               <ClaimsExchanges>
                  <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange_WithReadOnlyEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail" />
               </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <!-- Read the user after sign-up -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
               <ClaimsExchanges>
                  <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
               </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <!-- Issue the token -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
         </OrchestrationSteps>
      </UserJourney>
   </UserJourneys>
   <RelyingParty>
      <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUp" />
      <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
         <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
         <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
         <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
         </OutputClaims>
         <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
      </TechnicalProfile>
   </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>

